# How to include third party Python packages in Sublime Text 2 plugins

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, distutils, python-requests

I'm writing a sublime text 2 plugin that uses a module [SEAPI.py](https://stackapps.com/questions/3881/se-api-py-a-lightwight-python-wrapper-for-se-api) which in itself imports the [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Since sublime text 2 uses it's own embedded python interpreter, it doesn't see the requests module installed in my ubuntu machine (I get the following error: ImportError: No module named requests).

Best solution I could find so far was to copy the 'requests' module (the whole directory of files) from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests into my plugin directory in the sublime text packages dir.
But after that, it says that it can't find the 'urllib3' module.

Is there a better way to import the requests module so that I won't have to copy all the files into my plugin directory ?

The current code I'm using is as follows:

MyPlugin.py

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import SEAPI
...
```

SEAPI.py

```
import requests
try:
    import simplejson as json
except:
    import json
from time import time, sleep
...
```

**Edit:**
The selected answer is correct and fixes my main question, but a different problem exists with using the current version of 'Requests' with the embedded sublime text 2 interpreter. ST2's python is missing various modules which exist in regular 2.7 python (such as 'fileio').

I've solved it with using the 'Requests' module from here:
https://github.com/bgreenlee/sublime-github

And I had to edit the 'urllib3/response.py' file to this:

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO as BytesIO
except ImportError:
    pass  # _fileio doesn't seem to exist in ST's python in Linux, but we don't need it
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to bundle full requests distribution with your Python package and then modify Python's `sys.path` (where it looks for modules) to point to a folder containing `requests` folder.

- Download Requests library from a PyPi and extract it manually under your plugin folder
- **Before** importing requests in your plugin, append the corrcet folder to  sys.path to point a folder where it can found requests import

The (untested) code should look like something like this:

```
  import sys 
  import os

  # request-dists is the folder in our plugin
  sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "requests-dist"))

  import requests
```

This also assumes that `requests` `setup.py` does not do any hacks when you install the module using `easy_install` or `pip`.

You also could import `requests` zip directly as Python supports importing from ZIP files, assuming requests is distributed in compatible way. Example (advanced):

https://github.com/miohtama/ztanesh/blob/master/zsh-scripts/python-lib/zipimporter.py

More about sys.path trick (2004)

http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I have tried this - sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/")). It seems to see both the 'requests' module and 'urllib3' module which were installed with pip. But now it has the following error - File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/filepost.py", line 15, in <module>
    from io import BytesIO
  File ".\io.py", line 63, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _fileio

Comment: I have edited my question with a solution for this problem. Thanks again Mikko!

Comment: The information in this answer is **incredibly important** to creating Sublime Text plugins. It really should be in the official docs...

Comment: It is larger problem of Python community to decide whether requests should go to Python stdlib or not, not ST to alone tackle this

Comment: Or ST should just let their plugins be developed like any normal Python app (allowing use of a virtualenv, etc). Then we could just `pip install requests` and then `import requests` in the plugin's `main.py`.

Comment: @yourfriendzak Unforutnately the best and most promising open source sublime clone is being written in GoLang, and not python. [limetext](http://limetext.org/)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I mean a text editor that is actually not an underperformance, "website in a box" that doesn't even know what overtype mode is. (even MS word has overtype)

Answer (score 5):

Mikko's answer is good, but I may have found a slightly easier way:

```
import MyAwesomePlugin.requests
```

"MyAwesomePlugin" being the name of your plugin, of course.

Comment: This most likely breaks if requests library contains any absolute imports.

Comment: I haven't tested in that scenario, so you might be right. But let's hope `requests` avoids doing that because absolute paths are almost always a bad idea unless absolutely necessary.