# Sublime Editor Plugin Create GUI

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2

I am trying to create a plugin for sublime, with it's own GUI. Whatever I try, it seems `Tkinter` is not getting what it needs to run. Seems it needs some system variables to be set, which are unset when running a Sublime Text Plugin.

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1638, in __init__
    baseName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
```

Is it possible to pick up the required settings from somewhere?

Is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see sublimetext has its own python interpreter. And it seems to have overridden some of the default functionality. Argv ( The list of shell variables ) is not one of properties available. However are you sure you should be using Tkinter. I am on linux and I don't think Tkinter is available as a library. Not sure but does sublime build over Tkinter . I have not seen a plugin use it. I think you should look at this question.

[How to include third party Python packages in Sublime Text 2 plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180537/how-to-include-third-party-python-packages-in-sublime-text-2-plugins)