# pandas module in sublime text 2 + sublimeREPL?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I hope this question is legit here, I've been researching but not much luck so I figured it's worth a shot to post.

I've got Sublime Text 2 with sublimeREPL plugin installed. I'm able to run python 2.7.5 in the repl and it's pretty solid. My goal is to have sublime + repl as my IDE specifically with scientific packages, such as matplotlib, pandas, numpy, etc. As an example, I'd like to be able to `import pandas, pylab`, run some code through the repl and be able to plot something as if I did it from a typical ipython shell.

My question is that despite having the numpy, pandas, matplotlib packages installed via Enthought Python Distribution and being able to use them via IPython, I'm NOT able to do it via the REPL. I'm relatively new to package management like this, is there a way for me to get this working via REPL?

Comment: sounds good. What's your question?

Comment: @MattDMo edited question to actually pose a question =P

Comment: I think sublime uses it's own version of python, check via `import sys; sys.path`...

Comment: maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15180537/1240268 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/12342004/1240268

Comment: @AndyHayden - SublimeREPL is set up to use external interpreters, not the internal Python version. I'm guessing the OP has multiple Pythons installed on his system, and the wrong one is getting called.

Comment: You can build with sublime's internal version (which you can't change, so it's whatever your sublime shipped with). The issue isn't that I want my repl for a specific version of python, but more that I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to access installed packages through the repl, though I guess they're related.

Comment: @MattDMo yep, you can see which in the sublime repr not sure how you pip install to it though.