# Linking Sublime Text 2 to my Anaconda packages

Tags: python, sublimetext2

Sublime Text 2 can't access the packages I have (such as sklearn from Anaconda) whereas from the Terminal I can. How can I change this?

Anaconda [here](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration) gives instruction on how to link to other editors such as Pycharm, but I can't find anything on Sublime Text. Thoughts and solutions?

Comment: @Dawny33 That post seems to be directed to Sublime Text 3 (not sure if that makes a difference) and I think it assumes they are already linked and is giving instructions on how to change other settings, not how to link them. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sublime uses its own embedded python runtime. and In my experience it is a total pain to try to add any modules to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best doc you're going to find is the ["Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation"](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html)

This question asks about adding modules to sublime as well:
[How to include third party Python packages in Sublime Text 2 plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15180537/1695680)

Gist of the answer is to modify the embedded python's path to look for your modules.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named **Anaconda.sublime-build** in **~/.config/sublime-text-<2/3>/Packages/User/**
Edit the following contents of the file accordingly.

```
{
  "cmd": ["/home/<USER>/anaconda2/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Now go to sublime text. **Tools -> Build System -> Anaconda**.
You should now be able to build python modules using anaconda python in your system.

You can confirm the same using following commands.

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```