# Sublime Text 3 Plugin: How to load `enum` module?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to make a plugin for Sublime Text 3. I have a simple script loaded that uses the `enum` module.

However, when I `import enum`, I get an import error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'enum'
```

Using `sys.version`, I found that the version of Python run by Sublime is:

```
3.3.6 (default, Feb  2 2017, 05:49:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

It seems that `enum` is only available in Python v3.4+ . Is there a way to load the `enum` module from the version of Python I have installed globally (v3.6.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional searches, [I found a general solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180537/how-to-include-third-party-python-packages-in-sublime-text-2-plugins) to this issue. Although it's for Sublime 2 plugins, it seems to work for Sublime Text 3 as well.

I downloaded and unarchived the `enum` module [from PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum). I made the folder a subdirectory of my python script, and added the following before the `enum` import statement:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "<dir_name>"))
```

where `<dir_name>` was the name I gave to the directory containing the `enum` code.